# Angular Material mat-form-field's outline and mat-label is invisible when loaded first time

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui

I am using custom dark theme in angular material.
I have a login page which is just a form with an 'email' input and a password input.

Here is the *login.component.html*:

```
<form class="center-aligned p-20" #model="ngForm">
  <h3 style="text-align: left">
      Login:
  </h3>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="wide-input-field" color="accent">
    <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="pat@example.com" required type="email" ngModel>
  </mat-form-field>

  <br/>

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="wide-input-field" color="accent">
    <mat-label>Password:</mat-label>
    <input matInput required [type]="hidePass ? 'password' : 'text'" ngModel>
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix type="button"(click)="togglePassHidden()">
      <mat-icon>{{hidePass ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>

  <br/>

  <button mat-button color="primary" style="float:right;" (click)="handleClick()" type="submit">
    <div style="font-size:15pt;">Submit</div>
  </button>

</form>
```

Here is the login.component.css:

```
.p-20{
    padding: 20px;
}

.wide-input-field{
    display: block;
}

.center-aligned{
    text-align: center;
}

.left-aligned{
    text-align : start;
}
```

Now, when this page is loaded, it show this:

[image]

And when i click on one input field, or change the window size, their appearance becomes normal:

[image]

Is this because of the custom theming? I also removed the custom theme and it still doesn't shows outlines first time. I also changed my custom theme mode to light theme and the outlines are still invisible.

here's my custom theme, if that helps:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$primary-clr: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$accent-clr: mat-palette($mat-teal);

$dark-theme : mat-dark-theme($primary-clr, $accent-clr);
@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
```

and here's the package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "10.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.3.3",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I was also facing this issue last week. it was due to bootstrap and material classes conflicts. try placing these controls in a mat-container this should be resolved after that... else try removing bootstrap from your project and check if you are facing this issue...

Comment: @Zulqarnain thanks. I have already removed bootstrap, as you can see in my angular.json dependencies. I am teying the mat container

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil I am still facing the issue